# ASIHTTPRequest request responseHeaders objectForKey:@"Set-Cookie"

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

My code

[[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"Set-Cookie"]

and these result

cookiename1=1234; path=/; httponly, cookiename2=1234; path=/; httponly

**How to get only value of cookiename1?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your pending edit is the solution, add it as an answer instead and make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASIHTTPRequest I believe is a dead project, perhaps consider using another? I really enjoyed using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/)

What do you need that specific cookie for though. I believe the cookies under Set-Cookie should automatically be set for you by the library.

If you really need to actually look at the result, it is just a string, so you will have to do some string parsing. A regular expression would probably be best. I believe this example may work, but I do not know for sure. I cannot test at the moment, in fact I do not even have Xcode available at the moment. So there very well may be some syntax errors in this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"cookiename1=*;" options:0 error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regex firstMatchInString:cookies options:0 range:NSRangeFromString(cookies)];
NSString *stringResult = [cookies substringWithRange:[result range]];
```

Then from there you have the cookie from cookiename1=...; and you can extract it. Remove the trailing semicolon and finally split on "=" and you can get the value for the cookie.

Comment: Thank you mjb162 for the idea.

Comment: For AFNetworking, Could you explain more How to "send cookie along with a request in an Authorization HTTP header"? In code would appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Solved : 

After googling whole day!!

<pre>
NSArray *all = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[response allHeaderFields] forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"domainurl"]];

[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookies:all forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"domainurl"] mainDocumentURL:nil];
<code>

To call a request again use:

NSDictionary *headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:availableCookies];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

NSArray *availableCookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"domainurl"]];

Comment: I updated your question with your solution. I feel like that is much  more than needed though. `AFNetworking` should update the `NSHTTPCookieStorage` for your URL automatically if it receives a Set-Cookie from the server (infact just NSURLConnection does that for you also). Then all subsequent calls will use the cookies stored  for that URL will be sent automatically, you should not have to manually set or grab cookies, unless you have your own parsing to do. What happens if you build a request without setting the cookies?

Comment: Thanks again for your help mjb162. Yes, I forgot to set expiration date for the cookie on the server so, it was only session cookie!. That why my cookie was gone every time I restarted my app.

As long as a cookie's expiration date is set, it will automatically stored in sharedCookieStorage.

Anyways,I have learnt to handle with cookie manually!

Thank you.